# Using 'this' in jquery function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

My first question here... I have searched other Q&A but can't find exactly the point I'm looking for.

I'm a jquery begginer, so, of course, this makes much harder for me to adapt a solution to my problem.

So... I have the following code:

```
(function($){
$('select[data-select="cidades-distinct"]').ajaxSelect('http://www.myurl.asp', #destination);
})(jQuery);
```

I use it to fill, by ajax, a form select with city names, based on the country's state selection. So... to know which is the select that holds the state options I use the data attribute data-select. The city list is returned in #destination ID. The HTML code is:

```
<select data-select="cidades-distinct" id="myid" name="myname">
```

It works perfectly. But... If I want to use more than one list of states/cities, I cannot use this function, since it returns the list to the same ID #destination.

So, what I want to do is to pass my id destination name from the form, by a data attribute, like data-destination="#destination". So, my HTML code would be:

```
<select data-select="cidades-distinct" data-destination="#cidade" id="myid" name="myname">
```

But I can't do it! I tried the following code bellow and some variations, but there's something wrong!

```
(function($){
$('select[data-select="cidades-distinct"]').ajaxSelect('http://www.myurl.asp', $(this).attr("data-destination"));
})(jQuery);
```

Could you help me ?

Edit: adding ajaxSelect function
This is ajaxSelect:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    ajaxSelect: function(url, destino){
        return this.change(function(){
            var t = $(this),
                valor = t.val();

            $.ajax({
                'url': url,
                'data': {'valor': valor, 'action':'ajaxSelect'},
                'type': 'GET',
                'success': function(response){
                    $(destino).html(response)
                    $(destino).trigger("chosen:updated");
                },
                'error': function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    loading.hide();
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: you are making attribute `data-destination` but calling `$(this).attr("data-destino")` .Correct it `$(this).attr("data-destination")` or `$(this).data("destination")`

Comment: Sorry... I just copied it wrong... I changed variables names to make it easier to explain. Already edited it.

Comment: What `ajaxSelect` plugin are you using? Please link its docs.

Comment: What is `.ajaxSelect()` supposed to be?

Comment: ajaxSelect is a function that sends an URL with a parameter by ajax and returns the results to the #destination. I'm editing my question to add it.

Comment: @Sparky, could you take a look ? I tested the parameter with $(this).attr("data-destination") and got undefined... :(

Comment: Read the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The “this” Keyword
In JavaScript, as in most object-oriented programming languages, this is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the object on which a method is being invoked. The value of this is determined using a simple series of steps:

- If the function is invoked using Function.call() or Function.apply(), this will be set to the first argument passed to .call()/.apply(). If the first argument passed to .call()/.apply() is null or undefined, this will refer to the global object (which is the window object in web browsers).
- If the function being invoked was created using Function.bind(), this will be the first argument that was passed to .bind() at the time the function was created.
- If the function is being invoked as a method of an object, this will refer to that object.
- Otherwise, the function is being invoked as a standalone function not attached to any object, and this will refer to the global object.

```
// A function invoked using Function.call()

var myObject = {
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
    },
    myName: "Rebecca"
};

var secondObject = {
    myName: "Colin"
};

myObject.sayHello();                    // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
myObject.sayHello.call( secondObject ); // "Hi! My name is Colin"
```

---

```
// A function created using Function.bind()

var myName = "the global object";
var sayHello = function() {
    console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
};
var myObject = {
    myName: "Rebecca"
};
var myObjectHello = sayHello.bind( myObject );

sayHello();      // "Hi! My name is the global object"
myObjectHello(); // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
```

---

```
// A function being attached to an object at runtime.

var myName = "the global object";
var sayHello = function() {
    console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
};
var myObject = {
    myName: "Rebecca"
};
var secondObject = {
    myName: "Colin"
};

myObject.sayHello = sayHello;
secondObject.sayHello = sayHello;

sayHello();              // "Hi! My name is the global object"
myObject.sayHello();     // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
secondObject.sayHello(); // "Hi! My name is Colin"
```

When invoking a function deep within a long namespace, it is often tempting to reduce the amount of code you need to type by storing a reference to the actual function as a single, shorter variable. It is important not to do this with instance methods as this will cause the value of this within the function to change, leading to incorrect code operation. For instance:

```
var myNamespace = {
    myObject: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
        },
        myName: "Rebecca"
    }
};

var hello = myNamespace.myObject.sayHello;
```

hello(); // "Hi! My name is undefined"
You can, however, safely reduce everything up to the object on which the method is invoked:

```
var myNamespace = {
    myObject: {
        sayHello: function() {
            console.log( "Hi! My name is " + this.myName );
        },
        myName: "Rebecca"
    }
};

var obj = myNamespace.myObject;

obj.sayHello(); // "Hi! My name is Rebecca"
```

<kbd>[source](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)</kbd>